# Package and run multiple Android virtual machines through executable?

Tags: android, automation, android-virtual-device

Fairly new to posting on StackOverflow, apologies for any mistakes ahead of time.

Essentially, I want to create a project which will launch several AVD's (headless, meaning no GUI), download an app on all (i.e. Cookie Clicker, passive clicking game, *can this be done beforehand and saved to each device so it doesn't occur every launch?*), and begin executing clicks on each device.

*All of this is packaged in an executable file.*

What would be the best approach to this? I see several tutorials on executing this through the IDE eclipse, however, any guidance at all is appreciated.

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Emulators save their virtual "disk" into a file on your hard drive, so if you created an emulator, installed the game, then packaged those files up you could launch that emulator with the game on another device.  There are command line tools to launch emulators.  This is all pretty standard stuff for a test system.

Comment: Interesting, thanks! The goal is packaging this all in an executable down the line, where essentially I run the .exe and multiple instances of what I described above occur. Would you know any resources for learning how to accomplish that?